# AWS Deep Learning AMI with Python3.9

Tags: amazon-web-services, tensorflow, python-3.9

I tried using the formal AWS Deep Learning AMI.
It is published here: https://aws.amazon.com/marketplace/pp/prodview-d5wlsowr2cimk
(currently version 49.0)

My problem is that it uses `Python3.7` while my code uses `Python3.9`

I'm wondering what should I do. I can upgrade the python on the machine to 3.9, but this will obviously require reinstalling `TensorFlow` and other libraries, and I wonder if I will break the optimizations that come by default on this image.

I also couldn't find any other formal images of `Python3.9`, with GPU support and `TensorFlow`, `OpenCV` and others.

Comment: Are you experiencing any issues with the discrepancy in version?

Comment: What do you mean? it's python3.7, so my code with Python3.9 syntax doesn't work

Comment: Maybe it would be just easier to modify your code to run on p3.7?

Comment: Can you show code that works with python 3.9 and does not work with python 3.7?

Answer (score 0):

You can't use the the DLAMI virtual environment out of the box, yet you can create a new python virtual environment which imports all its content.

For example, you can edit `PYTHONPATH` and `LD_LIBRARY_PATH`:

```
export PYTHONPATH=$PYTHONPATH:/home/ec2-user/anaconda3/envs/<your environment>/lib/python3.7/site-packages
export LD_LIBRARY_PATH=$LD_LIBRARY_PATH:/home/ec2-user/anaconda3/envs/<your environment>/lib

<open python shell or run your script here>
```